# ESLint rule to detect uncalled functions

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a `Logger` class which beautifies the logs before showing them in JS browser console. I use `.bind()` to let console display correct script name and line (like `script_name.ts:62`) in the sources instead of always showing `Logger.ts:130`:

1. When I use `console.log.bind(console, ...args)` (correct script name and line):

   [image: expected view]
2. When I call `console.log(...args)` directly in the `Logger.log()` function (always the same line in `Logger` class):

   [image]

But there is a problem: I often forgot to call the function returned by `Logger.log()`. In this case I won't see any log in the console. Is there any ESLint rule which may help to handle this and show warning when this happens?

Roughly the `Logger` code is:

```
class Logger {
  log(...args: any[]) {
    // doing here something with log args
    return console.log.bind(console, ...args);
  }
}

// correct call
Logger.log("some text")();

// incorrect call (nothing will be shown)
Logger.log("some text");
```

I use this in browser extension in content scripts, this case doesn't work well with many existing logger libraries.

Comment: A pity that no answer addresses the question head on but rather suggests avoidance tactics. While this may be a good way, I am having the same problem in a completely different setting and thought already about some weird avoidance tactics, but don't like any of them.

Answer (score 1):

ESLint isn't really the problem here, your logger function is: if you want to know the actual location where things get logged, rather than trying to `bind` your way to victory (which is a losing battle), consider capturing the stack trace and removing everything up to and including the Logger.ts entry instead:

```js
class Logger {
  log(...args) {
    const callStack = (new Error()).stack.split(`\n`);
    let cruft = ``;
    do {
      cruft = callStack.shift();
    } while (!cruft.includes(`log`));

    // I'm checking for the `log` function name here, as
    // everything in this snippet lives in a single file,
    // but in your code this'd be `Logger.ts` or the like.

    // And after this shift loop, callStack[0] is now
    // the "real" location where you called log():
    console.log({
      location: callStack[0].trim(),
      arguments: args
    });
  }
}

const logger = new Logger();

function weShouldSeeThis() {
  logger.log(`some`, `values`, { a: [1,2,3]});
}

weShouldSeeThis();
```

With this approach, you can craft your logger function to do whatever you need to do (which certainly isn't console logging from the looks of it - because that's not the console =) in a way that you can precisely point to where a log action occurred.

Comment: This may be a workaround, however it doesn't solve the problem and add more difficulty during debugging in compare with double function call. As you see on the first screenshot, there is clickable script name and line like `content.ts:6` in the right part of console, so you can click it and immediately go to the sources tab to the needed line. In your solution it doesn't happen and script name and line is just a string.
Also I afraid creating `new Error()` to get the stack may be resource expensive (but I also may be wrong)

Comment: How would that change if you generate the same `filename:col:linenumber` data? ESlint (and really, any linter at all) will not be able to flag what you're doing as wrong in any way: the linter can never know whether returned functions need to be called (think of an `on` function that returns its corresponding `off`, or an `init` that returns its own `reset`) Just because it returns a function, doesn't mean that function will, or should, ever be used). As for new Error being resource intensive: yeah, you'd be wrong on that, it's part of the language with near-zero overhead =)

Comment: (Also, in case you're working with tools like VS Code: as long as the format is `filename:col:linenumber`, even if it's a completely random print, it will let you control/command-click that, so you can jump to that file at that location)

Comment: You right, it generate the same scriptname+line, but it doesn't generate the clickable link to open the Sources tab on needed line. Just to clarify, the logs are shown during runtime in the Console tab in browser (Google Chrome).

Comment: Regarding the ESLint rule I'm looking for, I suppose it should prevent misstyping like `console.log;` or `window.close;` or `[].push;` in the code. In the case when function expression is written but it wasn't called and nothing happens. This doesn't seems an syntax error and the code will run normally, but the result is obviously not reached.

Comment: Solution you propose is fine for debugging NodeJS app in IDE and it will show the correct clickable line, but I'm looking for solution for browser console.

Comment: fair enough - you'll want to ask this over on the ES lint issue tracker, because it sounds like something that's unusual enough to require the experts to pitch in.

Answer (score 0):

Would structuring this in a different way solve the problem?

```
console.log(…formatLog(‘some text’))
```

Alternatively it’s not as hard as you might think to write a simple
eslint plug-in. The code to create a Babel plugin is almost the same as as well, so the best solution might be to create a Babel plugin that converts `console.log` to do your custom formatting.

Comment: This seems more tough than double function call as you will need to import `formatLog()` also to each script where you call `console.log()`. But it looks as interesting idea.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-console? Might be a good starting point.

Comment: What I am thinking is you could use something like that plugin as a template to create a Babel plugin to inject  the `formatLog()` function every time it sees `console.log()`

Comment: This looks interesting but seems not exatcly what's needed. By the way, I seems found the solution to show correct script name + line (but it's not a solution for given question about ESLint rule, so I'll better post it to update to question)

Comment: I just found this https://github.com/tauren/babel-plugin-console-log which I think allows you to make custom log functions and keep the line number.

Comment: I got your idea about babel plugin, but if I understood correctly, it will transform the output code and will inject the `formatLog()` function to each `console.log()` call. It may be not so good idea, as my log function is roughly 100 lines and include a lot of stuff such as saving logs to send to remote server, adding colors and styles, serializing errors and objects to string, adding level margins etc. It will blow the output code a lot...

Comment: No it would just add the call, but that second plugin I added is even better, it allows you to create a custom `console.formatLog()` that preserves the line numbers.